# React Js Project not running Webpack local server

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I've just shutdown my local react app and tried to boot it back up and it keeps saying that its failing at my script start:dev is anyone able to help me debug the sprawl of log it spits out im not sure where its erroring.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
  "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
  "history": "^1.17.0",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "nouislider": "^10.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
  "react": "^0.14.6",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
  "react-html5-slider": "^0.2.1",
  "react-input-range": "^1.1.4",
  "react-modal-bootstrap": "^1.1.1",
  "react-nbsp": "^1.1.0",
  "react-rangeslider": "^2.1.0",
  "react-rangeslider-extended": "^1.0.10",
  "react-router": "^1.0.3",
  "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
  "webpack": "^1.12.9",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
  "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
  "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
  "reactjs-css-load": "^1.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm run start:dev",
  "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
```

}

This is the error i get

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~prestart: test@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: test@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\Desktop\reactapp\Workspace\bootstrap\app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\JRE\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\Desktop\reactapp\Workspace\bootstrap\app
11 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run start:dev' ]
12 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: test@1.0.0 start: `npm run start:dev`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid test@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd         C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\Desktop\reactapp\Workspace\bootstrap\app
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.11.0
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error test@1.0.0 start: `npm run start:dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script 'npm run start:dev'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the test package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     npm run start:dev
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs test
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls test
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

please help

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader', 'ignore-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy', ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
   filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

This is the Error that was requested

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~prestart: test@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: test@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\Desktop\reactapp\Workspace\bootstrap\app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\JRE\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\Desktop\reactapp\Workspace\bootstrap\app
11 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
11 silly lifecycle   'webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback' ]
12 silly lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle test@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: test@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid test@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\wilsona.CHECKMATE\Desktop\reactapp\Workspace\bootstrap\app
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v6.11.0
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error test@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the test package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs test
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls test
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: try this command instead `npm start`

Comment: @Sag1v npm start what? what modifiers do i add?

Comment: this the name of your start script.. it will run the `start` script that will call `start:dev`. i'm not sure but i think you can't call `run` on `start`. anyway if its not working post your webpack code

Comment: can you run this: `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback` ?

Comment: @MohamedIsmat Nope that errors too failed at test@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback'

Comment: could it be an issue where i have to reboot my pc cause it thinks its still running the server

Comment: edit your question and post the error you get when running `webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback`

Comment: @andywilson try updating your script to `'npm bin'/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --history-api-fallback`. (quotes around `npm bin` being backticks not apostrophe's)

Comment: @MohamedIsmat The Error is at the bottom of my question

Comment: @James It errors the same on that too im thinking its something with the package but wouldnt it have errored while i was using it not when i rebooted it

Comment: upgrade both npm and node, and try again. You're using an old version of npm (3.10)

Comment: i am updating it now to see if that is the issue im also going to clean npm cache

Comment: @MohamedIsmat i just updated to V6 and it still gives the same error

Comment: @andywilson cool, did you perform a clean install by any chance? The use of `^` is always risky in that sense (e.g. silent package updates). If so, my guess would be you were using an older version of webpack that just so happened to work on the version of Node you're using. One way to check would be look at the version in the `package.json` in the installed package vs the version you have in your  main `package.json`. More often than not when stuff just "randomly" stops working, it's a result of an unexpected package update (might not even be webpack).

Comment: well ive just deleted all the node_modules and i am reinstalling them all seeing if that fixes it also it just added package-lock.json well updating and reinstalling everything didnt fix it @James

Comment: @andywilson `package-lock` is something that was introduced in npm 5, it's basically just `npm-shrinkwrap` but it happens by default now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue i updated node and npm, then deleted all of the node_modules and did npm install again, then i put [] around 'babel-loader' and i removed 'ignore-loader'

Comment: That's good to hear! I wish the errors were a bit more clear.

Comment: @MohamedIsmat yeah the errors arent clear plus the weirdest thing was i havent added anything into that file or changed it in any way in about 3 days so thats the weird thing